# Multivariable derivatves of a function with respects to another function

Tags: calculus

So I've been trying to solve a question which turned out to come down to
$$u = x^2 + y$$
$$v = x + y^2$$
Where I have to determine $\frac{\partial v}{\partial u}$.

At this point, the solution just assumes this to be $0$, and I am not sure about how this would be proven as I could, for example, rewrite $v$ using $u$:
$$v=x + \left( u - x^2 \right)^2 $$

Is $\frac{\partial v}{\partial u} = 0$ valid and if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context, it is understood that you are changing from the coordinate system $(x,y)$ to the coordinate system $(u,v)$. Then $\partial f/\partial u$ means taking the derivative of $f$ with respect to $u$, holding *the other variables in that coordinate system* constant, in this case holding $v$ constant. So if $f(u,v)=v$, then $f$ is constant when $v$ is held constant, and its derivative is therefore zero.

Notation for partial derivatives is ambiguous, since it doesn't say what the other variables to be held constant are (unless you write something like $\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\right|_v$), so you need to figure this out from the context.